# Can't call functions from another header file when not in main

Tags: c++

So I have `test.h` which contains:

```
#ifndef TEST_H_
#define TEST_H_

class test {
public:
    int value;
};

#endif /* TEST_H_ */
```

and my `main.cpp`:

```
#include "test.h"

class Magic {
    test x;
    x.value = 2; // Syntax error
};

int main () {
    test y;
    y.value = 2; // Works fine

    return 0;
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: You cant put arbitrary code like this in a class declaration. That's how the language is defined.

Comment: What book/tutorial are you learning from that has code written like this?

Comment: So to use `test` I have to be in the main function?

Comment: You need to get a book on the basics of C++. You can use test in a class but it needs to be inside a function of some sort.

Comment: @CodyGray was just trying some things out. Great help by the way.

Comment: I wasn't trying to be mean. Two things: (1) There are actually really bad C++ books/tutorials out there, and I wouldn't be completely shocked if you replied with a link to one of them that had code like this somewhere. (2) Trying things out is a rather frustrating and unproductive way to learn a programming language. I highly recommend getting [a book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) that can help teach you and answer some of the simpler questions before you have to ask them.

Answer (score 3):

Assigning values like that is not valid syntax in a class definition in `c++`. The error has nothing to do with headers or whatever. Try putting everything in a single file and you will see the same behavior.

If you want to have default initialization of x.value to 2 for each instance of `Magic` define this in the constructor of `Magic`:

```
class Magic {
  test x;
  Magic() {
    x.value = 2;
  }
};
```